# What rebuilds tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript

On Mac, with Sublime Text 3, and Microsoft Typescript package.

When I add a .ts file, and I have a "filesGlob" entry in tsconfig file, and something or someone I thought would automagically expand the "files" entry based on what was found. This is not happening.

What bit am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What bit am I missing

The `filesGlob` is currently specific to `atom-typescript`: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md#filesglob (I've just updated the docs to make this more clear).

Comment: ah... But I was sure I saw it working at one point with Sublime Text 3, I think when I was using the arctic... typescript package.

Comment: @pitosalas some other packages might support it. But the official ones from microsoft don't

Answer (score 0):

This package https://github.com/Phaiax/ArcticTypescript does support the `file-glob` functionality introduced by `atom-typescript`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to generate the files property using the filesGlob patterns https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-glob regardless of IDE