# how does main.d.ts works in angular 2?

Tags: angular

In angular 2 project, there is this `typings.json` file and there is a `main.d.ts` in the typing folder where it references other definition files. in the app folder, none of the .ts file has the reference to the main.d.ts file but somehow the types/class info shows up fine there in all these ts classes. where's the magic come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is should come from your tsconfig.json.

Your tsconfig.json will have a section very similar to the one below. All your typescript files will be listed in files section of this file that will be auto generated from something like [grunt-typescript-using-tsconfig/](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-typescript-using-tsconfig).

```
"filesGlob": [
  "./<dir where you put your typings>/**/*.ts",
  "./typings/main.d.ts"
]
```

The magic comes from filesGlob section of tsconfig. A related posting in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172836/what-rebuilds-tsconfig-json)

Comment: Here's the tsconfig.json. {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "!node_modules/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
} when I add a type definition to the main.d.ts the type def is not picked up by the consumers.

Comment: ok, looks like adding them to the main.d.ts won't work, need to add them to a different file. this main.d.ts might be excluded.

Comment: In your tsconfig.json, your excluded main.d.ts as per  "exclude": [ "node_modules", "typings/main", "typings/main.d.ts" ]

Comment: Yup, noticed that. Thx @Suresh